# how to fetch a column as an associative array key in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-7

I have a table  `order_tbl` & `transaction_tbl`

`order_tbl`

```
  id   order_id  product_id  qty  amount
-----  --------  ----------  ---  ------
  1       1         1         1     10
  1       1         3         1     20
  1       2         2         2     30
  2       2         3         1     20
```

`transaction_tbl`

```
 id   order_id  total_amount
----  --------  ------------
  1       1          30
  2       2          50
```

Now I want to fetch data as an associative array from `order_tbl` where key will be `order_id` like below format.

```
[1(this is order_id)] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                (
                    [0]=>1(this is product_id)
                    [1]=>3(this is product_id)
                ),
                [1] => Array
                (
                    [0]=>1(this is qty)
                    [1]=>1(this is qty)
                )                
            )

[2(this is order_id)] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                (
                    [0]=>2(this is product_id)
                    [1]=>3(this is product_id)
                ),
                [1] => Array
                (
                    [0]=>2(this is qty)
                    [1]=>1(this is qty)
                )                
            )
```

I make a query but not getting the exact output

```
DB::table('orders')
            ->join('order_details','order_details.orders_id', '=', 'orders.orders_id')
            ->select('order_details.product_id', 'orders.orders_id as orders_id, order_details.quantity as quantity')
            ->get()
            ->keyBy('orders.orders_id')
            ->toArray();
```

Anybody Help Please? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
$yourorderlist=DB::table('orders')
            ->join('order_details','order_details.orders_id', '=','orders.orders_id')
            ->select('order_details.product_id', 'orders.orders_id as orders_id, order_details.quantity as quantity')
            ->orderby('order_id', 'desc')
            ->get();
```

Comment: Please format your code and add a little explanation on why/how this solves the question

Comment: @Pon Ranith...If I put `keyBy` before `get()`...it will gives an error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::keyBy()`

Comment: get() method should use in last only in here you remove keyBy and check with where condition it will work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).